# 'getPointer' of undefined in fabricjs using angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, fabricjs

I am using [Angular 4](https://angular.io/). If user clicks on the canvas, I want to get the coordinates of mouse, but when I call `getPointer` I am getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPointer' of undefined
at klass.<anonymous> (studio.ts:84)
at klass.fire (fabric.js:260)
at klass._handleEvent (fabric.js:10851)
at klass.__onMouseDown (fabric.js:11013)
at klass._onMouseDown (fabric.js:10681)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:3)
```

My code:

```
import 'fabric'; 
declare const fabric: any;
export class StudioPage {
   ngOnInit() {
        this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('drawing_layer', {
         width: 500,
         height: 500
        });
   }

   coordinates(){
    this.canvas.off('mouse:down', false);
    this.canvas.observe('mouse:down', function (o) {
       console.log(this.canvas.getPointer(o.e));
    });
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this.canvas does not have the desired value apparently. Maybe you can share the logs within your browser's developer console?

Comment: `this` inside the callback function does not refer to your `StudioPage` object. Try using `(o) => {console.log(this.canvas.getPointer(o.e));});` instead of `function (o) {console.log(this.canvas.getPointer(o.e));});`